# How to initialize a member-array of class type variables?

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor

I want to create a member array of 10 `Foo`, each initialized to `Foo(8, "10")`, something like this:

```
Foo bar = new Foo(8, "10")[10]; //like this
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you want a member array of 10 `Foo`, each initialized to `Foo(8, "10")`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Exactly. That's what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to initialize 10 objects of the type `Foo`, you should use a [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) in C++:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos( 10, Foo(8, "10"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a `std::vector` like this:

```
struct A {
   std::vector<Foo> bar;
   A() : bar(10, Foo(8, "10")) {}
};
```

`std::vector` can be used just like a normal array, plus some neat extra functionality documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

If the dynamic allocation of the `vector` proofs to be too slow and the number `10` is a compile time constant, you can use an `std::array` instead. However, the syntax is not as pretty and the difference is most likely negligible.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the array is constant and small, you can use:

```
foo array_of_foos[3] = 
{
    foo(8, "10"),
    foo(8, "10"),
    foo(8, "10")
};
```

The only other way would be to use a for() loop, but for this to work foo must also have a no-parameter constructor (aka `foo()`)

xtofl's answer using vectors works too, assuming you can use a vector instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

If an array has a small size then you can explicitly specify an initializer for each element of the array.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A( int x, int y ) : x( x ), y( y ) {}
    int x, y;
};    

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    A *a = new A[N] 
    { 
        { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, 4 }, 
        { 5, 5 }, { 6, 6 }, { 7, 7 }, { 8, 8 }, { 9, 9 }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i].x << ' ' << a[i].y << std::endl;

    delete [] a;

}
```

The program output is

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

But if you are going to allocate dynamically an array then a better approach is to use standard class `std::vector` declared in header `<vector>`.

You can use the same initializer list as for example

```
    std::vector<A> v = 
    { 
        { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, 4 }, 
        { 5, 5 }, { 6, 6 }, { 7, 7 }, { 8, 8 }, { 9, 9 }
    };
```

Or you can at first to initialize all elements with a default value

```
std::vector<A> v( N, { 0, 0 } );
```

and then reassign them using for example a standard algorithm like `std::fill`, `std::generate` and others.